# Registry Editor on Lumia 800?

Tags: lumia, rooting, homebrew

Is there any possibility to edit the registry on a Nokia Lumia 800?
I know there are options to get one on HTC devices but it seems there is no for Nokia phones.

Comment: I have had rooted phones ever since I transfered to the smart phone world and it is AMAZING. Improved battery life, speed, the ability to change system level preferences.. It's definitely worth it. There is a way to flash a ROM back to your phone that is completely stock, and will (seemingly) keep your warranty on your phone if you still have it. Check on xda like @Joe said, but you should be safe (just follow directions closely, you'll be fine). However, it's all based on comfort level, so do what you feel comfortable with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1626010) on the XDA forums, and it looks like it is possible. I don't have an L800 to test it, but the aforementioned link does give you some instructions on how to do it.  Links are also included on unlocking your phone, and installing the Root Tools. For bonus points, the thread also includes some key registry changes you can make.

**Proceed with caution** Should you brick your phone, or otherwise screw it up, I wouldn't count on getting support from Nokia or your carrier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also did further research and I think this is the only possible solution. But I think it's not a solution for me - I'll keep with the default registry settings and don't risk to brick my phone. ;)